# How do I cut the last characters and save them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, python-requests

I have a script generator that creates uncompressed public keys. The script works with the **"bitcoin"** module.

As a result, I get uncompressed public keys that consist of `130` HEX characters.

It's `04 [x, y]`

I need to change the code so that only the last `25` characters are saved in the result. That is, for public keys to be cut and saved to a file
**"Pubkey.txt"**

```
import bitcoin

with open("Privkey.txt","r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
# you may also want to remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
f.close()


outfile = open("Pubkey.txt","w")
for x in content:
  outfile.write(""+bitcoin.privtopub(x)+"\n")

outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

if `bitcoin.privtopub(x)` returns a string then you can just slice it.

```
bitcoin.privtopub(x)[-25:]
```